# How to troubleshoot SpringBoot app on AppEngine - Java 11 environment

Tags: spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

My spring boot app in Google Appengine (Java 8)  is failing to start

I tried java 11 model, but I cant even run that app locally to debug  (***one version of basic java 11 app worked, but adding more dependencies is breaking, so decided to use existing App that is Java 8 based***)

```
 ./mvnw -DskipTests clean package appengine:run

appengine:run is only available for appengine-web.xml based projects
```

Java 8 Spring Boot:

App is not starting. I am struggling to understand what logger is used

I see this dependency

> implementation
> 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-logging-logback:0.121.3-alpha'

So assumed logback

my logback.xml in src\main\resources

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/logging/logback-appender.xml" />
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml" />

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <!-- If running in GCP, remove the CONSOLE appender otherwise logs will be duplicated. -->
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
                
    </root>
</configuration>
```

I tried adding stackdriver and did not get it working, now I am tired, and don't want to try stackdriver. too many possibilities - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/docs/current/reference/html/logging.html

(Note from website: Currently, only Logback is supported and there are 2 possibilities to log to Stackdriver via this library with Logback: via direct API calls and through JSON-formatted console logs.)

Cant debug from App Engine >> Instances . As it disappears and also shows "Resident" . No SSH ?

How can I get good debug level logs to identify the problem ? Is it memory issue or any system problem

[image]

another deployment logs - this doesn't even tell log level (except that i like info at the start)

[image]

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this document](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/java#jul_handler)? Please, also share if you are using GAE in a standard or flexible environment.

Comment: Hi @OsvaldoLópez I tried both . I presume flex means F1 etc. As I had no clue of the BlackBox aka Appengine , I tried a bigger machine B4_1G to see if there is out of memory ( read that spring apps face out of memory at startup). So many variables java 8 vs java 11, app-engine web vs app.yaml , logback vs logging.props., and on top of it these new BOMs increase package from 90MB to 157MB . A freaking mess